# Remove .html from url in apache2

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I am trying to remove .html 
so the site is www.example.com/login

login.html is located in /var/www/html/login.html

I created .htaccess in /var/www/html/.htaccess

And I put in:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

This doesn't seem to work. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: this is a duplicate question. What you're trying to achieve is pretty urls, take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530614/htaccess-and-php-redirects-and-pretty-urls

Comment: This doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Apparently you changed your question.

Comment: It turns out I had it at /var/www/html/.htaccess. However when I do it, I get this error message -> Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled on your system?

Comment: This is still not working for me on my website, how would I enable mod_rewrite @PanamaJack

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```