# How do I resolve this .htaccess conflict?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I have the following .htaccess rule in order to enable "clean" URLs, i.e. strip the .html extension from file names:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

It works perfectly in 90 percent of directories on the site, except for directories that have an index.html in them.  Linking to those directories as /directory results in the following error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /directory/.html on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Linking to these directories as /directory/index is not desirable, because URLs with "index" in them are not presentable.

To get around this issue, I tried renaming those few index.**html** files to index.**htm**, but that results in the same error message when accessing /directory.

I am especially confused about this part:

> You don't have permission to access /directory/.html on this server.

Why does Apache think that I am trying to access /directory/.html when in reality I am trying to access index.htm?

***Edit:***
Per Panama Jack's request, I am posting the entire .htaccess file below

Original:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Edit #1:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Here are a few entries from the apache error log
These errors happen with my original .htaccess

```
client denied by server configuration: /home/user/public_html/ar/.html
File does not exist: /home/user/public_html/403.shtml
client denied by server configuration: /home/user/public_html/zh_TW/.html
File does not exist: /home/user/public_html/403.shtml
```

These errors happen with the Edit #1 version of htaccess:

```
File does not exist: /home/user/public_html/en/directory1, referer: http://example.com/en/directory1
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://example.com/en/directory1
File does not exist: /home/user/public_html/en/directory2, referer: http://example.com/
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 3):

Try your rules this way.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Edit:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: That helped with the index.html error, but now there is another error.  Not Found.  The requested URL /directory was not found on this server. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Can you add the rest of your .htaccess rules to your question.

Comment: I have added both versions to the question, thank you.

Comment: What does your URL look like when you get this error message about /directory above?

Comment: When trying to access example.com/file1, the URL bar shows http://example.com/file1 and the browsers shows 404 and 500 errors.  When trying to access example.com/file1.html, the URL bar shows http://example.com/file1.html and the browser shows the page correctly.

Comment: Tried it, same result

Comment: Try and clear your browser cache or try in an new browser. If you're simply removing the extension then that should work.

Comment: Just tried it in IE (was using Chrome and Firefox before), it still doesn't work.  Typing a URL without .html results in an error, and typing it with .html shows the page but does not remove the extension.  Is there a way I could send you the site's URL privately?

Comment: Well see if you can check your apache error logs to see what it says specifically when you get that error. It should be helpful.

Comment: I have added a few entries from the error log to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Is this your document root? `/home/user/public_html` what do you have in your vhost file for this site? Make sure it's allowing access.

Comment: I have edited the question to include different types of errors for my original htaccess and for your version of htaccess.  It looks like some syntax in your version is throwing apache off, and the rewrite is not working correctly.

Comment: wait, where exactly is your .htaccess file? Because in the error I see an `en` sub directory and you didn't have that in your question.

Comment: .htaccess is in public_html.   en, fr, es, and others are language directories that include both subdirectories and html files.

Comment: That really makes a difference how rules are created. You also have to account for en, fr ,es or you will continue to get 404s. Give me a **real** full URL minus the .html extension. And change the domain name if you want.

Comment: There are over 700 HTML files, all in different directories.  Which URLs would you like?  Like I said earlier, the majority of them are working with my original rules.  In fact, all html files that are NOT named index.html are working.  They only ones that are not working are the few remaining index.html files that can be found in various directories and subdirectories.

Comment: Did you try setting the directory index? `DirectoryIndex index.html` at the top of the .htaccess file.

Comment: I just tried it adding that to both versions of .htaccess, and it doesn't do anything.  But I think we have strayed too far from the actual issues in the question.  If you look in the apache errors that I've provided per your request, your rules are not rewriting the URLs correctly.  There is an incorrect loop probably somewhere in the syntax.

Comment: I know those rules work. I've provided them several times. Even the updated version I put back does work. You can probably even google and find similar answers. The rules should work. Something else is going on.

Comment: I believe you, but how do you explain this error then?  Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.  It only happens when I replace the original rules with your edited version.  Also, the .html extension is removed correctly in the original version but not in the edited version.

Comment: I'm not sure, I've seen that happen when caching issues in the browser and clearing them has helped or using a different browser to test. Even my edited version of my answer should def work in a normal situation.

Comment: But you realize that the original rules worked perfectly, right?  I only need to take care of the few remaining index.html files, and I thought that renaming them to .htm would be the easiest solution, because the rewrite rule wouldn't touch them then, but that didn't work.  That's why I opened this question.

Comment: They didn't work totally remember because you were getting the directory index.html issue and you said `That helped with the index.html error, but now there is another error.` but either way you still should use this on your original rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: It's working!  Everything started working after adding that line to the original .htaccess.  So it was your rewrite rule that was breaking it :)   But yay it's working now.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad you finally got it.

Comment: If you want to amend your answer to include that line, I can mark it as correct.  Thanks again!

Comment: I already did, it's the very first answer I made. Not my edit.

Comment: This is how the rewrite rule should look: RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]   The version that you currently have (with the forward slash instead of backward slash) doesn't work.

Comment: This `/?` that means the forward slash is optional. That's what the ? means. If you don't put one apache will still do the rewrite. That is valid regex and it's used all the time. So that means you can use `example.com/file1` or `example.com/file1/`

Comment: Also here is a good example of what my first answer was that I know works.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582225/remove-html-from-url-in-apache2/30582392#30582392 But anyway, you have yours working so that's fine.

Comment: I have no doubt that it worked in the other case.  It just didn't work for this site.  I'd troubleshoot it more, but I'm afraid to break it again after fixing broken links all night.